# Assigning command's output to shell variable and get the variables size

Tags: file, shell, awk, grep

I have a file consisting of digits. Usually, each line contains one single number. I would like to count the number of lines in the file that begin with digit '0'. If it's the case, then I would like to do some post-processing.

Although I'm able to retrieve correctly the corresponding line numbers, the total number of retrieved lines is not correct. Below, I'm posting the code that I'm using.

```
linesToRemove=$(awk '/^0/ { print NR; }' ${inputFile});
# linesToRemove=$(grep -n "^0" ${inputFile} | cut -d":" -f1);

linesNr=${#linesToRemove} # <- here, the error
# linesNr=${#linesToRemove[@]} # <- here, the error

if [ "${linesNr}" -gt "0" ]; then
    # do something here, e.g. remove corresponding lines.
    awk -v n=$linesToRemove 'NR == n {next} {print}' ${anotherFile} > ${outputFile}
fi
```

Also, as for the awk-based command, how could I use a shell-variable? I tried the command below, but it's not working correctly, since 'myIndex' is interpreted as a text and not as a variable.

```
linesToRemove=$(awk -v myIndex="$myIndex" '/^myIndex/ { print NR;}' ${inputFile});
```

Given the line numbers starting with `0` found in `${inputFile}`, I would like to remove the corresponding lines numbers from `${anotherFile}`. An example for both ${inputFile} and ${anotherFile} is given below:

```
// ${inputFile}
0 
1
3
0

// ${anotherFile}
2.617300e+01 5.886700e+01 -1.894697e-01 1.251225e+02
5.707397e+01 2.214040e+02 8.607959e-02 1.229114e+02
1.725900e+01 1.734360e+02 -1.298053e-01 1.250318e+02
2.177940e+01 1.249531e+02 1.538853e-01 1.527150e+02

// ${outputFile}
5.707397e+01 2.214040e+02 8.607959e-02 1.229114e+02
1.725900e+01 1.734360e+02 -1.298053e-01 1.250318e+02
```

In the example above, I need to delete lines `0` and `3` from `${anotherFile}`, given that those lines correspond to the lines starting with `0` in `${inputFile}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of lines in the file that begins with 0, then this line is wrong.

`linesToRemove=$(awk '/^0/ { print NR; }' ${inputFile});`

The above says to print the line number when the line start with 0, and your `linesToRemove` variable will contain all the line numbers, not the total number of lines. Use `END{}` block to capture the total. eg

`linesToRemove=$(awk '/^0/ {c++}END{print c}' ${inputFile});`

As for your 2nd question on using variable inside awk, use the regex operator `~`. And then set your `myIndex` variable to include the `^` anchor

`linesToRemove=$(awk -v myIndex="^$myIndex" '$0 ~ myIndex{ print NR;}' ${inputFile});`

finally, if you just want to remove those lines that start with 0, then just simply remove it

```
awk '/^0/{next}{print $0>FILENAME}' file
```

If you want to remove lines from another file using what is captured in input file, here's one way

```
paste -d"|" inputfile anotherfile | awk '!/^0/{gsub(/^.*\|/,"");print}'
```

Or just one `awk` command

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /^0/{a[FNR]} NR>FNR && (!(FNR in a))' inputfile anotherfile
```

crude explanation: FNR==NR && /^0/ means process the first file whole line starts with 0 and put its line number into array `a`. `NR>FNR` means process the next file and if line number not in array, print the line. See the gawk documentation for what FNR,NR etc means

Comment: @ghosdog74, thanks! Well, actually the final goal is to retrieve the lines starting with 0 in one file, and then delete those corresponding lines from another file. Furthermore, couldn't it be possible to use the size/length of the variable 'linesToRemove' to find the total number of lines?

Comment: @Javier, you should post a sample of those files, and show your final output. I can show you better, if not more efficient ways than what you are doing now

Comment: @ghosdog74, I updated the post and included some samples of both files.

Comment: @Javier, you should have done that in the first place. See my edit

Comment: @ghosdog74, by using the one-line `awk` command, the output is not as the one explained above. It also shows the line numbers in `inputfile`. As from the example, I would like to retrieve only the lines from `anotherfile` by which I'm sure, there was not a line starting with `0` in `inputfile`.

Comment: @ghosdog74, great! I did some tests and it seems to that it's perfectly working! Do, you mind in explaining a bit the code? Also, I guess, if no matches are found (`/^0/`), then the original files remain unchanged, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do the following to assign an array:

```
linesToRemove=( $(awk '/^0/ { print NR; }' ${inputFile}) )
```

And to get the number of elements do (as you have in a commented line):

```
linesNr=${#linesToRemove[@]}
```

To remove the lines from from the file you could do something like:

```
sedCmd=""
for lineNr in ${linesToRemove[@]}; do
  sedCmd="$sedCmd;${lineNr}d"
done
sed "$sedCmd" ${anotherFile} > ${outputFile}
```

Comment: thanks! By having the line numbers starting with `0` in the `linesToRemove` array, how could I use it to remove those line numbers from a file?

Comment: @Javier: I added an example for a `sed` command using the `d` (delete) command.

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to speed up the code? I have several files to process, and to execute the code above for only one file it takes already some time.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you do this:

```
linesToRemove=$(awk '/^0/ { print NR; }' ${inputFile});
```

instead of this:

```
linesToRemove=$(awk '/^0/ { print NR; }' ${inputFile});
linesNr=${#linesToRemove}
```

use this:

```
linesToRemove=$(awk '/^0/ { print NR; }' ${inputFile});
linesNr=${echo $linesToRemove|awk '{print NF}'}
```

POC  :

```
cat temp.sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

lines=$(awk '/^d/{print NR}' script.sh)
nooflines=$(echo $lines|awk '{print NF}')
echo $nooflines
torinoco!DBL:/oo_dgfqausr/test/dfqwrk12/vijay> temp.sh
8
torinoco!DBL:/oo_dgfqausr/test/dfqwrk12/vijay>
```

Comment: "newlines converted to tab"??? not so. If you fail to "quote" the variable, then your variable is subject to shell word splitting (http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit)

Answer (score 0):

It greatly depends on the post-processing you are doing, but do you really need the actual count?  Why not do something like this:

```
if grep ^0 $inputfile > /dev/null; then
  # There is at least one line with a leading 0
  :
fi

grep -v ^0 $inputfile | process-lines-without-leading-zero
grep ^0 $inputfile | process-lines-with-leading-zero
```

Or, even just:

```
if grep ^0 $inputfile | process-lines-with-leading-zero; then
  # some post processing
  :
fi
```

--EDIT--

Based on what you've said in your comment, I would recommend a different approach.  If I understand you correctly, you want to read file a, looking for lines of the form ^0[0-9]*,
and then remove those line numbers from file b.  Doing it one line at a time is pretty slow if the files get big.  Just do:

```
cmd=$( grep '^0[0-9]*$' a | sed 's/$/d;/g' )
sed "$cmd" b
```

The assignment to cmd forms a sed command to delete the lines.  Invoking sed on b will omit those lines.  You'll need to redirect the sed output appropriately (perhaps to a temp file and then back to b, or just use 'sed -i' if you're using gnu sed.)

Comment: thanks! Actually, what I need to do is to find first the lines that begin with `0` in file `A`, and then remove those lines from file `B`. I updated my original post and inserted the command that I'm using to remove the retrieved lines.

Comment: @javier.  If no lines match, then cmd is empty and the final sed is a no-op, and b will be unchanged.

Comment: I got the following message: `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: invalid usage of line address 0`, after calling `cmd=$( grep '^0[0-9]*$' ${inputFile} | sed 's/$/d;/g' )` and then `sed "$cmd" ${anotherFile}`

Comment: @Javier  What do you want to do when you encounter "000" in file a?  you could just skip it by adding "| grep -v '^0*$' " into the pipeline that builds cmd, or maybe you want to handle it differently. Build the command appropriately; sed does not recognize line 0 as a valid address.

Comment: From other comments, it appears that you do not care about the content of the line in file a, but just the line number it appears on.  In that case, build cmd differently: cmd=$( grep -n ^0 a | sed 's/:.*/d;/g')

Answer (score 0):

Given the large number of edits to this question, it seems easiest to start a new answer.  Your problem can be solved with a simple one-liner:

```
$ sed "$( grep -n ^0 $inputFile | sed 's/:.*/d;/g' )" $anotherFile > $outputFile
```